# Why is this object unassigned?

Tags: python

Trie is a list of nodes:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, parent, daughters, edge):
        self.parent = parent
        self.daughters = daughters
        self.edge = edge
        trie.append(self)
        self.index = len(trie) - 1

def TrieConstruction(patterns):
    global trie
    for node in trie:
        print('Node: ', node.parent, node.daughters, node.edge, node.index)
    trie.append(node(0, [], 0))
    ...
```

The program gives this error:

```
File "trieMatching.1.py", line 22, in TrieConstruction
    trie.append(node(0, [], 0))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'node' referenced before assignment
```

I don't know why this variable would be unassigned; doesn't the function understand that 'node' is a class and that I am instantiating it?

Comment: local variable `node` in the for loop is shadowing your `node` class. Rename it and you'll be good to go. Also please follow [`PEP8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) coding conventions regarding class names.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `for node in trie:` is an assignment too. If `trie` is an empty list then `node` remains unbound.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're right; I didn't think that would *"unbind"* `node` if `trie` was empty (rather than just not shadow it) but clearly it does.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: It is not just assignments that mark names as locals; imports, nested  functions and classes, `except` and `with` statement `as` targets  as well as `for` loop targets mark a name as *local*, and until you actually bind to the name trying to use the name raises the unbound local exception.

Comment: @MartijnPieters having thought about it, that makes perfect sense; thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the name `node` for both the class and the `for` loop target:

```
class node:
    # ...

for node in trie:
    # ...
trie.append(node(0, [], 0))
```

If `trie` is empty `node` will remain unbound in the function as there are no values to assign to it.

You'll have to rename one of those. I suggest you follow the [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) and use CamelCase for class names:

```
class Node:
```

and lower_case_with_underscores for your function (and a name better reflecting the responsibility):

```
def construct_trie(patterns):
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Trie was empty.

Comment: Actually I don't understand. "If trie is empty node will remain unbound in the function as there are no values to assign to it.". No values to assign to node? Shouldn't a class instantiation be possible in any local scope?

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks again

Comment: @user6309: if you `trie` had not been empty you'd have gotten a different error because you'd have tried to use the last node in the sequence as the class.